# iOS UI Update and Asynchronous Method

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiview, social-networking, uiprogressview

I'm using iOS 6's Social API to send tweets, and I want to have an progress view. Following is the message to show.

```
    [self.progressView addStatus:@"Posting to Twitter"];
```

Since my App would possibly send messages to multiple destinations at the same time, I'd like to display all processing status on the progress view. So once a new message is add to the progress view, I'll build a subview and then add it to the main progress view.

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];

UIActivityIndicatorView *weiboIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
weiboIndicator.tag = tag + 1;
[weiboIndicator setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 20, weiboIndicator.frame.size.width, weiboIndicator.frame.size.height)];

[containerView addSubview:weiboIndicator];
[weiboIndicator startAnimating];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34, 23, 40, 60)];
label.tag = tag;
label.text = status;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.hidden = NO;
[label sizeToFit];

[containerView addSubview:label];
```

It's a very simple UIView.  Then I add it to the main progress view

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[ParallelProgressView sharedView] addSubview:progressVivew];

        //change height to accommodate new progress view
        [[ParallelProgressView sharedView] setFrame:CGRectMake(bounds.size.width / 4, bounds.size.height / 4, bounds.size.width / 2, (index + 1) * 60 + 40 )];
        //[[ParallelProgressView sharedView] setNeedsDisplay];
    });
```

**the problem is the activity indicator shows immediately, but not the label**

[image]

the indicator is animating, and height of the view has changed. **But the label doesn't shows until a short period later.**
[image]

Comment: You have to perform your UI change on the main Thread

Comment: @elio.d dispatch_async runs the UI change code on main thread. UIActivateIndicator is showed

Comment: I'm having a similar challenge on this.  Was a solution found?

Comment: I ended up re-architecting my solution to avoid manipulating UI outside of the main thread.